# Linux: How to get files with a name that ends with a number greater than 10

Tags: linux, bash, filenames, sh

I have some files that have names like this: 'abcdefg_y_zz.jpg'
The 'abcdefg' is a sequence of digits, while the 'y' and 'zz' are letters.
I need to get all the files that have the sequence of digits ending with a number greater than 10. The files that have 'fg' greater that 10.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that in a bash script?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, technically, based on all your info...

`ls | grep '[0-9]{5}[1-9][0-9]_[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]{2}.jpg'`

Comment: Thank you, it actually works.
I changed it to '[0-9]{5}[1-9][1-9]_*.jpg' to be more accurate and it works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: hopefully you meant [1-9][0-9] - otherwise your leaving out multiples of 10

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Just exclude ones which have 0 in position f.

```
ls -1 | grep -v "?????0?_?_??.jpg"
```

**Update** 
Since you want > 10 and not >= 10, you'll need to exclude 10 too. So do this:

```
ls -1 | grep -v "?????0*_?_??.jpg" | grep -v "??????10_?_??.jpg"
```

Comment: this line seems to give me those that are <= 10. I suppose that if I have a list with all the files, I can eliminate these from the list and the remaining ones are the ones I'm looking for, right?

Answer (score 0):

with more scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in seq FIRST INCREMENT LAST
do
cp abcde$i_y_zz.jpg /your_new_dir //or whatever you want to do with those files
done
```

so in your example line with seq will be

```
for i in seq 11 1 100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames are orderly named this `awk` solution works:

```
ls | awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "5 2" } $2 > 10'
```

#### Explanation

- `FIELDWIDTHS = "5 2"` means that `$1` will refer to the first 5 characters and `$2` the next 2.
- `$2 > 10` matches when field 2 is greater than 10 and implicitly invokes the default code block, i.e. `'{ print }'`

Answer (score 0):

Just one process:

```
ls ?????+(1[1-9]|[2-9]?)_?_??.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions provided so far are fine, but anybody who's had some experience with shell programming knows that **parsing `ls` is never a good idea and must be avoided**. This actually doesn't apply in this case, where we can assume that the names of the files follow a certain pattern, but it's a rule that should be remembered. More explanation [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

What you want can be achieved much safer with GNU `find` - assuming that you run the command in the directory where the files are, it would look something like this :

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./[0-9]{5}[1-9][0-9]_[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]{2}.jpg$'
```